# Custom Colormap (cmap) rasterio, Python

Tags: python, rasterio, matplotlib, colormap

I wish to display custom colours for the pixel values in my raster. How can I create a custom colormap (cmap)?
In the example below, I have specified "magma" as the colour map. However, I wish to define my own colors for specific range/values.

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show,show_hist


if __name__ == "__main__":

    input_Dir = 'generated_46.tif'
    src = rasterio.open(input_Dir)
    show(src,cmap="magma")
```

Here the result of the above code

[image]

Comment: Have a look at https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html#creating-listed-colormaps and https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html#creating-linear-segmented-colormaps

Comment: Do you know how to save it to the JPG file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

```
levels = [0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.8, 1, 2, 4, 7, 17, 70, 500]
    clrs = ['#E3E8E81A','#3DFDFF8C', '#3CFAFF', '#6A95FF', '#E61AFE8C', '#FF04FF', '#f4ded9', '#f4dbaa', '#eda14f', '#e87511', '#b55400', '#633b11']
    
cmap, norm = colors.from_levels_and_colors(levels, clrs,extend='max')

show(src,cmap=cmap,norm=norm,interpolation='bilinear')
```